Issue with building a version of Blender 4.1.1 (GooEngine)
I've been trying to build a version of Blender from its github. It kinda works i can open it fine and work on it. But in the cmd prompt, i get this message:
Read prefs: "C:\Users\etulyon1\AppData\Roaming\Blender 

Foundation\Blender\4.1\config\userpref.blend"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 365, in enable
    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\python\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from bpy_extras.io_utils import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'poll_file_object_drop' from 'bpy_extras.io_utils' (C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\io_utils.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 365, in enable
    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\python\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper, ExportHelper, poll_file_object_drop
ImportError: cannot import name 'poll_file_object_drop' from 'bpy_extras.io_utils' (C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\io_utils.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 365, in enable
    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\python\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from bpy_extras.io_utils import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'poll_file_object_drop' from 'bpy_extras.io_utils' (C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\io_utils.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 365, in enable
    mod = importlib.import_module(module_name)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\python\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\blender-git\build_windows_x64_vc17_Release\bin\Release\4.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper, ExportHelper, poll_file_object_drop

I can open it and work on it fine. The only thing that doesnt work for the moment is Eevee. The app just crashes once i open it. I didnt notice any other issues for now.
Would really appreaciate some insight on it. Ty.

The error messages indicate that Blender is attempting to load some add-ons (io_scene_fbx and io_scene_gltf2) but fails because it cannot import a specific function (poll_file_object_drop) from the bpy_extras.io_utils module.
If you just download Blender from https://blender.org/download it should include these which would fix your errors.

Tysm dude, i copied the addons into the build and it worked.

Niceeee, glad I could help!
